# How can I change transform?

Tags: modeling, transforms

[image]

Hi, how can I change transform pivot like this red arrows ?

Comment: Hi, not so clear: do you wish to move the pivot from its current location shown above to a new location(red cross)?

Comment: Just above the Timeline is the 3D Manipulator Widget (The symbol is 3 Axis red/blue/green. Next to that is a drop down menu w/ Global,Local Normal & View options. It is affected by the direction of the normal(s) selected though.

Comment: @m.ardito Yes i want this red and blue cross will be on this my paint red cross. I want to move this brick model In the direction of those my paint red cross.

Comment: @Dontwalk I have selected normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I got what you ask but it seems that your rectangular mesh outlined in green has its local axes not aligned to its vertical/horizontal ides (probably you applied its rotation for some reason), and now you wish to make your local axes "realigned" in order to be able to "move" the mesh along one of those axes.

If you need this, you have to help your "axes realignment" with a separate object, say an empty.

1. you add an empty
2. you place it on one of your mesh "corners" helping with snap tools
3. you also use snap tools to rotate the empty, aligning one of its axes to one of your mesh sides
4. then you copy the empty rotation value (eg: 138.516796°)
5. then you rotate the mesh of a value of "180° - 138.516796°"
6. now your mesh is perfectly aligned with the grid, so you apply this new mesh rotation, which gets you good "local" axes
7. then you rotate "back" your mesh of the same amount but inversed ("138.516796° - 180°" => note, in the animation below I did this wrong), to rotate back the mesh where it was at the beginning (but now you have aligned local axes)
8. then you can move your mesh along the desired direction

See how it works:

[image]

Hth